# Flutter - Use Image.Network with cookies

Tags: image, cookies, flutter

I want to get an avatar image from my Rest api but I have to pass a cookie, otherwise I have a 401 unauthorized.

Is it possible to use something like an Image.Network to do that ?

Comment: you have `headers` parameter which is passed to underlying `NetworkImage` provider

Comment: I don't know how I missed it... Thank you @pskink.
How do I close this issue ?

Comment: write a self answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These is a header parameter that I missed.

Here is what I do :

```
 Map<String, String> headersMap = {
  'Cookie' : 'jwt-cookie=eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiI0IiwiaXNzIjoiMSIsInN1YiI6InRtYSIsImlhdCI6MTU1NjExNTY2MCwiZXhwIjoxNTU2NzIwNDYwfQ.DQMV59lTlGSgVN_viwlUaJIxZNO_Sru0gQT31EnKZEdD533OR9VUCRYaj5pY8ist48zRUmn6HXs4M_oWkkzm7A'
};
```

I set my cookie in a map called headersMap, then I can set my headers in the headers parameter like that :

```
Image.network(baseURL + userService.currentUser.id.toString(), headers: headersMap,)
```

For more customisation I just found this [plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_advanced_networkimage)

Thanks to @pskink for the solution.